# Generating https action url for the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to generate a https URL for the `action` of a form. It should function on all servers, live, stage, and localhost.

In localhost: `localhost:port/submiturl` - no need to https here.

In live: `https://domain.com/submiturl`

In stage: `https://stage.domain.com/submiturl`

I cannot put the whole page under SSL, but I specifically need to put the action of the form.

How can I do this programmatically?

Edit:

I've tried `action="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", null, "https")"`

But it generates `https://localhost/Controller/Action` in localhost, which is not correct.

Comment: @Dan, have you tried HTTPs URL rewrite, posted below?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried HTTP URL rewrite, you can specify condition and write code to redirect to HTTPS if request it is received from domain.com and stage.domain.com.

Following are some links that might be helpful.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sojesh/archive/2009/05/26/http-to-https-redirection-using-asp-net-http-module.aspx
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module
[ASP.NET - rewriting all https requests to http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076469/asp-net-rewriting-all-https-requests-to-http)