# IIS8 - Hosting SSL and Non-SSL site on same server

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, https, windows-server-2012

I want to host SSL and non-SSL site on the same server.

Basically I would have:

http://example.com/site1

https://example.com/site2

Is it possible? I have read that it causes non-ssl site to respond to ssl request [issue link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276860/iis-7-adding-ssl-to-one-site-all-other-sites-responds-to-https-request)

Will appreciate if you somebody can point me to step by step instructions how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a sub domain to achieve this, for example:

http://example.com/site1

https://secure.example.com/site2